# Background become black but the content of the modal doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, html, web, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the modal attribute. When the user click on the image it suppose to display some text I have write the following code.

```
<div class="col-md-4 gallery-left">
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" href="#myModal" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
      <img class="img-responsive lot" src="{% static 'img/toothbrush.jpg' %}" alt="">
      <div class="b-wrapper">
          <div class="b-animate b-from-left b-delay03 ">
              <i class="plus second"> Picture description </i>
          </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The background become black but there is no content that is display.
I have succeed to use the modal to display the image on which the user is clicking using the following code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" href="{% static 'img/toothbrush.jpg' %}" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
```

Why it doesn't work when I'm trying to display a div with text instead of the image?

Comment: Please post the complete relevant code

Comment: It would help if you could put up a JSbin of this or something equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned the things around a little bit.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-md" href="#myModal" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
```

Should be

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
```

i.e reference the `id` of the modal markup. Or you should actually add `bs-example-modal-md` as class to `#myModal` :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-md" role="dialog">
```

Both will work. In either case you should use `href="#"`. Here example with `#myModal` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/03m1fzso/** in my opinion the best solution since targeting a class can lead to unclarity when you reexaminate the code, besides the risk of using the class more than once by accident.